# Trap remove-item exception

Tags: powershell, powershell-trap

In powershell there is some exception that I am not able to trap or I am not doing to correct things.

So here is the code that does the things:

```
log "Processing $($_.Name).old" $logFile
if (Test-Path "$($_.Name).old" )
{
    & { 
        rm "$($_.Name).old" 
    }
    trap #[System.UnauthorizedAccessException]
    {
        log "Move to trash" $logFile
        moveTrach "$($_.Name).old" 
        continue
    }
}
```

I had comment out the type in the trap expression to be sure to catch anything.
But unfortunately I never go into the trap clause.

I can see the exception log but not the "Move to trash" log.

```
2012-02-16 10:35:31 Processing file.dll
Remove-Item : Cannot remove item file.dll.old: Access to the path 'file.dll.old' is     denied.
At upgradegw.ps1:189 char:29
+                         rm <<<<  "$($_.Name).old" 
+ CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (file.dll.old:FileInfo) [Remove-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveFileSystemItemUnAuthorizedAccess,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
2012-02-16 10:35:31 Processing file2.dll
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trap will only trigger on a terminating error.

```
  rm "$($_.Name).old" -ErrorAction "Stop"
```